# Unable to connect via SFTP2 using SSH Tectia Client

Tags: windows-7, sftp

I have been using SSH Tectia Client for SSH and SFTP to my UNIX machine.
There is not private authentication added for this profile.

Recently, this machine OS has been re-imaged. So, the host-key has been replaced.

Now, I am unable to connect to this VM via SFTP through SSH Tectia Client installed on windows.

Do I have to update anything in ~/.ssh folder in windows to update the host-key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: *"File transfer Server could not be started or it exited unexpectedly. Exit value 0 was returned. Most likely the sftp-server is not in the path of the user on the server-side"*  I am able to connect through SSH to this VM but not able to connect to SFTP for file transfer.

Comment: Can you connect using any other SFTP client?

Comment: Have tried using FileZilla FTP Client as well using DEBUG mode. *Error: Connection closed by server with exitcode 128
Trace: CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Error: Could not connect to server
Trace: CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)*

Comment: You should check server-side log to determine why the SSH server fails/rejects to start SFTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  Any particular file that should be of interest? And how to set the log level to debug in server side?

Comment: I do not know how your SSH server is configured. Assuming OpenSSH, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause of this problem. From what I have browsed through it is said that this problem could have been due to some errors after executing the configuration files like .bashrc etc. 
So, using tbe command "ssh -p hostname uname", I got an error stating undefined variable "variableName" along with the uname of the VM.
I have handled the undefined variable accordingly and restored the sftp.